# unexpected results with JS prototype inheritance

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I have a base class like:

Stage.js:

```
function Stage(name) {
  this.my_name = name;
}

Stage.prototype.name = function() {
  return this.my_name;
}

module.exports = Stage;
```

Parallel:

```
var Stage = require("./Stage");

ParallelStage.prototype = Stage.prototype;

ParallelStage.prototype.execute = function() {
  console.log("+++ Executing stage " + this.name()+ " in parallel...");
  return this;
}

function ParallelStage(name) {
  Stage.call(this,name);
  return this;
}

module.exports = ParallelStage;
```

and Serial.js:

```
var Stage = require("./Stage");

SerialStage.prototype = Stage.prototype;

SerialStage.prototype.execute = function() {
  console.log("+++ Executing stage " + this.name()+ " in serial...");
  return this;
}

function SerialStage(name) {
  Stage.call(this,name);
  return this;
}

module.exports = SerialStage;
```

However when I run:

```
var Parallel = require ("./ParallelStage");
var Serial = require ("./SerialStage");

var parallel = new Parallel("Extraction");
parallel.execute();
```

I get the following output:

```
+++ Executing stage Extraction in serial...
```

I am clearly missing something fundamental about javascript and prototype inheritance. Can someone clue me into what I am missing here? I was expecting it to show a stage execution in parallel not serial...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proper prototype inheritance you have to use

```
var child.prototype = Object.create(parent.prototype, {...object with properties/methods...}
```

When you call

```
SerialStage.prototype = Stage.prototype;
```

You loose `SerialStage.prototype` object as it referenced to `Stage.prototype` and as result your last inherited object always override properties and method of prototype.
So edit you code and change ways of inheriting

```
ParallelStage.prototype = Object.create(Stage.prototype);
```

and

```
ParallelStage.prototype = Object.create(Stage.prototype);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the prototype for both `serialStage` and `ParallelStage` to be `Stage.prototype`, so now you're basically working with the same prototype object for all three methods.

When you write something to that prototype, it overwrites anything that might have the same name, for instance

```
var Stage = function Stage() {}

ParallelStage.prototype = Stage.prototype; // set to Stage.prototype
ParallelStage.prototype.execute = function() {} 
// ^ you've attached an "execute" method to the Stage.prototype object


SerialStage.prototype = Stage.prototype; // set to the same Stage.prototype
SerialStage.prototype.execute = function() {}
// ^ you've just overwritten the "execute" function in Stage.prototype
```

You could use `Object.create`, `Object.assign` and a number of other solutions to create a copy of the prototype object, so as to not overwrite it's properties each time, but that sorta defeats the purpose of inheriting it in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

When you do:

```
SerialStage.prototype = Stage.prototype;
```

you're not creating a copy of the base prototype - it's an assignment, and like any other assignment it points at *the existing object*. So instead of giving unique prototypes to `ParallelStage` and `SerialStage`, you're reusing the same prototype for both constructors. And when you assigned the execute method you've overwritten the existing once, not created a new one.

A quick and easy fix would be to do this instead:

```
ParallelStage.prototype = new Stage();
```

and

```
SerialStage.prototype = new Stage();
```

This creates a new object for each prototype, which you can then put the methods on. Prototype delegation will ensure that property lookups go up the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you are using Stage's prototype in the following line:

```
ParallelStage.prototype = Stage.prototype
```

`ParallelStage.prototype` is now just a pointer to `Stage.prototype`. When you modify it you are replacing the parent's function for all objects using the Stage prototype.

Your specific problem occurs because Serial.js is executed after Stage.js and Parallel.js; it's changes to `Stage.prototype` are the last ones and are in effect for any objects of type `Stage`, `SerialStage` and `ParallelStage`.

The correct way to inherit a prototype from a parent (or one of the correct ways) is to use the following:

```
Child.prototype = Object.create(Parent.prototype)
```

Change your code to use this pattern and you should get the behavior you're after.